# SweetAlert : Need To Increase the size of text area

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

I am unable to increase the `text-area` of the sweet alert that `pops-up` , I would want to reset it according to my specification , I am able to increase the modal height and width , not the `text-area`. Need inputs on that

tried `.swal-height` and `.swal-width` in CSS and gave the appropriate `classname`. But unable to set the `text-area` size.

```
handleDelete() {

var delreq;
var response_data;
var response_jsonObj;


swal("Enter notes:", {
  content: "input",
}).then((value) => {
  isDeleted = "Yes";
delreq = {
  "DeleteRequest":
    [
      {
        "Param-1": val1,
        "Param-2": val2,
        "Param-3": "val3",
        "Param-4": val4,
        "Param-5": val5
      }
    ]
};
console.log('delreq',delreq);
fetch('API_URL', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, application/xml,  */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(delreq)
}
).then(response => {
  if (response.status !== 200) {

    return;
  }
  response.text().then(data => {

    response_data = data;
    response_jsonObj = JSON.parse(response_data);
    this.setState({ delval: response_jsonObj });

  });
}).catch(error => this.setState({ error }));

swal({
  title: "Deleted Successfully!",
  icon: "success",
  confirmButtonText: 'OK'
}).then((okay) => {
  if (okay) {
    history.push('/page1');
    history.push('/page2');
  }
});
});
```

}

want the `text-area` to be bigger than what it is appearing as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved . I used the latest version of SweetAlert that is Sweetalert2 which made things easier for me. I used the code snippet from SweetAlert2's official website (https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to get things done. Here it is :

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Submit your Github username',
  input: 'text',
  inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: 'off'
  },
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Look up',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (login) => {
    return fetch(`//api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText)
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(
          `Request failed: ${error}`
        )
      })
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: `${result.value.login}'s avatar`,
      imageUrl: result.value.avatar_url
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like above try using SweetAlert 2 instead, I have a similar issue and just put

```
.swal2-popup {
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
}
```

on the CSS style of your module and this helped me for the text and the text are which I guess is auto size depending on your font-size